# what does animal.__class__.__name__ does in the following code

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

What does `animal.__class__.__name__` do in the following code? I have a class `Animal`, which is the superclass, and classes `Lion` and `Tiger`, which both inherit class `Animal`. Wow does it work?

```py
from project.animal import Animal
from project.worker import Worker


class Zoo(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, budget, animal_capacity, workers_capacity):
        self.name = name
        self.__budget = budget
        self.__animal_capacity = animal_capacity
        self.__workers_capacity = workers_capacity
        self.animals = []
        self.workers = []

    def add_animal(self,animal: Animal,price):
        if price <= self.__budget and self.__animal_capacity > len(self.animals):
            self.animals.append(animal)
            self.__budget -= price
            return f"{animal.name} the {animal.__class__.__name__} added to the zoo"

        if self.__animal_capacity > len(self.animals):
            if self.__budget < price:
                return f"Not enough budget"
        else:
            return "Not enough space for the animal"
```

Comment: `animal.__class__` returns the specific subclass of the variable. And `.__name__` returns that class's name as a string. So if the variable contain a `Lion`, it will be `"Lion"`.

Comment: However ... making `Zoo` a subclass of `Animal` is probably a mistake.  Since when is a zoo an animal in the real world?  How many legs does a zoo have?  What does it eat?

Answer (score 0):

`animal.name` gives you the value of the user-defined attribute `name` of the object `animal`, whereas `animal.__class__.__name__` tells you the name of the class of the object `animal` which was defined in the definition of the class. E.g.

```py
class Lion (Animal):
    name: str 

my_lion = Lion()
my_lion.name = 'Simba'
print(f"{my_lion.name} is a {my_lion.__class__.__name__}")
```

The code above will print out "Simba is a Lion"

Answer (score 0):

In the given code 'animal.**class**.**name**' is used to retrieve name of the class which 'animal' object belongs

so it work like:

for example if you have object 'lion' created from 'Lion' class

lion.**class**.**name** will return string 'Lion'

I hope that it will work like that.